# Why I get different dates in mozzila and chrome with specific timezone?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, internet-explorer, datetime-format

If I have the following javascript code:

new Date('2016-11-15T00:00:00+0100')

Gives me different results in Chrome and Mozilla and IE
-   Chrome and Firefox: creates an object set at last midnight, local timezone
-   IE: creates an object with no time set as it does not recognize the format

Can anyone knows how to create a date like that who work on IE Mozilla and Chrome the same with specific timezone?

Comment: Please check https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for some explanation on browser issues when parsing dates. If you can, I recommend you using that library.

Comment: @Darlesson not working